# rails wrong association has_many link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Trying to set up very basic association between Customer and Contact model.

```
Customer has_many :contacts 
Contact belongs_to :customer
User has_many :customers
```

Routes

```
    resources :customers do
      resources :contacts
    end
```

I don't want /contacts to be accessible

When I add in my views

```
new_customer_contacts_path
```

I have an error. If I have

```
new_customer_contact_path(contact)
```

it works however link to contact#show is wrong 
--> it directs to customers/7/contact/2 where it should be customers/2/contact/7

Any idea?

Comment: Edit your question if you need more clarification. Don't post an answer. Also, you'll probably want to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta tell the customer whose contact belongs_to!

Like the following:

```
# Customer.first and Contact.first can be exchanged to instances 
# of Customer or Contact!

new_customer_contacts_path(Customer.first)
edit_customer_contact_path(Customer.first, Contact.first)
customer_contacts_path(Customer.first)
```

Comment: Not my point. I want to access customers/ID/contacts/ID not the first customer. Plus the new action works fine so why not the show or edit?

Comment: `Customer.first` was just an example! Rails doesn't know how to complete any nested routes if you don't specify the parent object! Try `edit_customer_contact_path(customer,contact)` where customer and contact are instances of `Customer` and `Contact` and you'll see what i'm talking about!

Answer (score 0):

```
new_customer_contact_path(contact)
```

This is wrong. You should pass customer to it instead of contact.

If you want to show the contact of a customer, you should use customer_contact_path(customer, contact).

For reference, go to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and search 'Creating Paths and URLs From Objects'

Answer (score 0):

With nested routes you need to pass the objects (or at least their ids) in the order they are listed in the route.  In the case of 'new' you only need to pass the parent object id as there is no id yet for the new nested object.

`new_customer_contact_path(customer)`